# Android: Jpeg saved from camera looks corrupted

Tags: android, android-camera

I'm writing an Android application that saves a JPEG snapshot from the camera when the user clicks a button.  Unfortunately, when I look at the JPEG file my code is saving looks corrupted.  It appears to be caused by my call to parameters.setPreviewSize (see code snippet below) - if I remove that then the image saves fine; however without it I can't set the preview size and setDisplayOrientation also appears to have no effect without it.

My app is targeting API Level 8 (Android 2.2), and I'm debugging on an HTC Desire HD.  Not quite sure what I'm doing wrong here... any help would be very much appreciated!

Cheers,
Scottie

```
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
    // Now that the size is known, set up the camera parameters and begin
    // the preview.
    Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();        
    Camera.Size size = getBestPreviewSize(w,h);

    // This next call is required in order for preview size to be set and
    // setDisplayOrientation to take effect...
    // Unfortunately it's also causing JPEG to be created wrong
    parameters.setPreviewSize(size.width, size.height);

    parameters.setPictureFormat(ImageFormat.JPEG);
    mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
    mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);

    mCamera.startPreview();

}

// This is the snapshot button event handler
public void onSnapshotButtonClick(View target) {
    //void android.hardware.Camera.takePicture(ShutterCallback shutter, 
    //                              PictureCallback raw, PictureCallback jpeg)
    mPreview.mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mPictureCallback);
}


// This saves the camera snapshot as a JPEG file on the SD card
Camera.PictureCallback mPictureCallback = new Camera.PictureCallback() {
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] imageData, Camera c) {

        if (imageData != null) {
            FileOutputStream outStream = null;
            try {
                String myJpgPath = String.format(
                        "/sdcard/%d.jpg", System.currentTimeMillis());

                outStream = new FileOutputStream(myJpgPath);
                outStream.write(imageData);
                outStream.close();
                Log.d("TestApp", "onPictureTaken - wrote bytes: "
                        + imageData.length);

                c.startPreview();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.format("%s written", myJpgPath), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Happens for me too, but only for the HTC Desire HD. The jpeg saves fine on the Samsung Galaxy S and the emulator.

Comment: @jA_cOp - Thanks for that, at least I know it's not me that's wrong!  The camera app in the Android source code works ok, so I'm going to have a study of that and spot the difference.

Comment: Have you solved the problem? i've bumped into the same problem, only with HTC Desire HD

Comment: @Ikky - I've not had a chance to come back to this project yet, will update here when I do

Comment: If setPreviewSize not nessecary, try to remove the parameters.setPreviewSize, that worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

Another workaround is to match the aspect ratio between preview and picture sizes (i.e. setPreviewSize(w1,h1); setPictureSize(w2,h2) with w1/h1 ~ w2/h2 (small differences seem to be ok)). E.g. for Desire HD S  w1=800,h1=480, w2=2592,h2=1552 works as well as w1=960,h1=720,h2=2592,h2=1952 (if you don't mind distorted images ;-)

Comment: I can confirm this on my HTC Desire S device. By the way, on the native camera app on this device, you can define in the settings both the aspect ratio (4:3 or 5:3) and the resolution. The list of available resolutions depends on the aspect ratio because it seems they need to match.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you are using a common implementation of the getBestPreviewSize(w,h) method that is floating about, where you cycle through the different getSupportedPreviewSizes() to find the best match.  Although I am not certain as to why it causes the images to be distorted, I have found that calling the parameters.setPreviewSize(size.width, size.height) method with the output of the getBestPreviewSize method is what is causing the problem on the HTC Desire.  I have also verified that by commenting it out, the distorted image issue goes away.

Comment: I have a similar issue with my app and removed the setPreviewSize, some users (Desire S) still got the issue. So this is not something only related to this portion of code. I have seen a lot of post around this and really like someone could explain the very details of why the picture appears like this

Comment: Great response ! I've been looking for exactly that for the last few hours while struggling with the distorted images I get from onFramePreview when converting to YUV. Thanks a lot !