# save picture in new directory

Tags: android, android-camera, filewriter

i want too save images in my own directory this is perhaps the directory on which the images are been saved

```
  Uri uriTarget = getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, new ContentValues());

OutputStream imageFileOS;
```

and this is were i am giving my image uri Target where the image will going to be save

```
 imageFileOS = getContentResolver().openOutputStream(uriTarget);

                imageFileOS.write(arg0);

                imageFileOS.flush();

                imageFileOS.close();
```

how can i achive that by making my own directory and saving image there

Comment: Just give the right value to  `uriTarget`. Assign `my own directory`.

Comment: thats what i am asking how to assign that just like **"sdcard/Myapp"** or there is something else ?

Comment: You probably mean /sdcard/Myapp. How did you determine /sdcard ? Do not hard code paths. Have a look at Uri.fromFile() to convert a File instance to an uri.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to take a picture and then crop it then stored it on SDCard. 
Here are codes, maybe you will be inspired:

**Take a photo**:

```
        Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
        intent.putExtra("return-data", false);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                Uri.fromFile(AVATAR_FILE_TMP));
        intent.putExtra("outputFormat",
                Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG.toString());
        intent.putExtra("noFaceDetection", true);
        startActivityForResult(intent, CODE_TAKE_PHOTO);
```

`Then crop the photo`:

```
if (requestCode == CODE_TAKE_PHOTO) {
    cropImage(Uri.fromFile(AVATAR_FILE_TMP));
}
public void cropImage(Uri uri) {
    Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
    intent.setDataAndType(uri, "image/*");
    intent.putExtra("crop", "true");
    // aspectX aspectY 是宽高的比例
    intent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
    intent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
    // outputX outputY 是裁剪图片宽高
    intent.putExtra("outputX", 400);
    intent.putExtra("outputY", 400);
    intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
    startActivityForResult(intent, CODE_CROP_IMAGE);
}
```

And at last, **store the picture**:

```
            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            if (extras != null) {
                Bitmap photo = extras.getParcelable("data");
                // civAvatar.setImageBitmap(photo); // 把图片显示在ImageView控件上
                FileOutputStream fos = null;
                try {
                    // store the picture
                    fos = new FileOutputStream(AVATAR_FILE);
                    photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);// (0-100)compress file.
                    AVATAR_FILE_TMP.deleteOnExit();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    IoUtils.closeSilently(fos);
                    finish();
                }
            }
```

And if you just store the picture, `intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(AVATAR_FILE_TMP));` is OK.

Answer (score 0):

The solution involving heavy Bitmaps is (IMHO) irrelevant when your phone or camera is taking JPEGs.

See the solution here for an almost instantaneous solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7982964/5426777

```
new FileOutputStream(myPath).write(byte[] myPictureCallbackBytes)
```